# Python Requests Unable to Handle 403 Error

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm getting a 403 error from a request I'm making (which is fine that's not the issue). However, I can't seem to catch an except and properly handle the error. My code just moves on like nothing went wrong and is causing other issues.
Code

```
    try:
        verify = True if os.environ.get('environment', 'dev') != 'dev' else False
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=verify)
        return response.content
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        print('Error', e)
        return None
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Connection refused", e)
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print("Internal error", e)
        return None
```

Is there something else I can try?

Comment: A 403 result isn't an exception.  None of the `except` code is executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To capture 403 you need to raise exception. This can be done by calling `response.raise_for_status()` after the post. see [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/).

```
try:
    verify = True if os.environ.get('environment', 'dev') != 'dev' else False
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=verify)
    response.raise_for_status() # This will throw an exception if status is 4xx or 5xx
    return response.content
except requests.HTTPError as e:
    print('Error', e)
    return None
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("Connection refused", e)
    return None
except Exception as e:
    print("Internal error", e)
    return None
```